# Powershell - 'PUT' files to URL that require parameters

Tags: bash, powershell, format, webrequest

I've been trying for a while now to find a way in Powershell to take a list of files and upload them to a URL. (ive been able to do it in Unix Bash no problem).
However, I think there are issues with the parameters passing in and the URI building - causing a 500 internal server Error.
What I currently have is this:

```
$logfiles = "\\location\trace\logs" 
$buildName = "NewBuild"
$EngineName = "DefaultEngine"

$request = "http://localhost:9005/parser/singleUploadTracerLib.do? 
blockingUpload=true&autocommit=true&tracerSetName=$buildName&$EngineName"


foreach($f in $logfiles | Get-ChildItem) {
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Verbose -Method PUT `
                    -Infile $f.FullName -ContentType 'application/octet-stream' 

}
```

When I do this in bash - i have no issues (see below for comparison) so i assume I need to pass in the prams another way?

In Bash(works):

```
    ls -N ${pathToLogs} |  grep clean | sort | xargs -I {} echo  "-F 
inputs[]=@${pathToLogs}{}" | xargs curl -X POST
  "${Url}/parser/singleUploadTracerLib.do?  
blockingUpload=true&autocommit=true&
tracerSetName=${buildName}&EngineName=${engineName}"
```

any kind person got any ideas? it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `&EngineName=$EngineName`

Comment: Your bash command uses `POST`, whereas your PowerShell command uses `PUT`. Your bash command uses `&EngineName=<value>`, whereas your PowerShell command uses just `&<value>`.